# Spring MVC rest service not accessible on Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, google-app-engine

I am using Spring MVC to expose some rest services. I have exposed them in this manner:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testpath")
public class ConcreteMyController implements MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public String testGet(@RequestBody HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        return "here is a string";
    }
}
```

After deploying on Google App Engine I notice that I cannot access https://mydomain.appspot.com/testpath without getting a 404 error.

I tried changing it to a HttpServlet and then it is working like this:

```
public class ConcreteMyController extends HttpServlet  {

    @Override
    public String doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  {
        PrintWriter respWriter = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setStatus(200);
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        respWriter.println("here is a string");

    }
}
```

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>package.ConcreteMyController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PlusSampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/plussampleservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>any</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/anotherpathIamusing</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd


        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="package.config"/>
</beans>
```

In the config package I have a file looking like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("package.model.repository")
@ComponentScan("package")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    //Omitted datasources
}
```

The Spring MVC code has been working before I made this a Google App Engine project. Now I have to use a HttpServlet to expose services. How do I make the Spring MVC option work? Help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: Regarding the web.xml, I have posted the code for both with and without Spring MVC. When testing I am only using one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Removed my servlet mapping for Spring MVC in web.xml and replaced with this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It is working fine like this.